# Load more images on scroll (without mysql)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, load, scroll

i have this php code who auto thumb and arrange my photos to gallery:

```
<?php
$folder = "../albums/1000/";
$folder3 = "albums/1000/";
$handle = opendir($folder);
$noeffect = "noeffect";
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
                if (strpos($file, '.png',1)||strpos($file, '.jpg',1)||strpos($file, '.JPG',1) ) { 
$imgsrc= "../thumbnail.php?file=";
$imgend= "&width=120&height=120";
    echo ("
    <li><a href=\"".$folder.$file."\" rel=\"".$rel.external."\" class=\"".$noeffect."\">
 <img src=\"".$imgsrc.$folder3.$file.$imgend."\" /></a></li> "); }}
?>
```

it works great and i love it! but when i upload 200-300 pictures it need to load the thumbs before it could view the big picture in the gallery.. and i thought how can i make load more button or load more on scroll to load like 30 pictures a time..
i search the net and tried many but most of them use mysql and i dont know how to deal it and others were problematic.. any solution? thanks!

You can take a look here for example for what im doing : http://m.eladhamemagnet.net/albums/996.php

btw its for iphone so thats why i need it to load fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did pre loading for every picture and it worked..

Answer (score 1):

First, use javascript to start pre-loading the large picture on DOM ready. This will make sure the thumbs load first. When the thumbs are done loading, then start loading the "big pictures" via javascript. This will result in the large pictures being cached by the browser and display instantly.

Second, browsers will only open up to 8 connections at a time to any domain. Older browsers use less. This means with 30 pictures, it will take 4 "rounds" of loads to get everything. That doesn't include html, css, and javascript files. There is no way to load 30 pictures at a time. If you can setup subdomains and assign images to load from each subdomain, your images will load as fast as the user's connection can handle. Or your server can serve. You do want to make sure each image is always loaded from the same subdomain so the browser will cache it between page loads.

As an example, you can see how fast a full page of thumbs loads on a site I manage (shameless plug) bigstockphoto.com. Once the page is done loading, javascript/ajax starts loading the larger "hover" images. If you set the images per page to 160, over 320 images are loading per page (160 thumbs + 160 large images).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the image library to merge all the thumbnails into a big single image, then use CSS positioning to display each one in its own div.

This way, the browser loads one image only. All the thumbnails appear at the same time, but if you have hundreds of images, you might want to break them into smaller groups so the sprite is not too big a file.

```
    <?php
$images_dir = './images';
$thumb_height = $thumb_width = $sprite_width = 120;

// List the images to process
$sprite_exists = false;
$list = array();
if ($handle = opendir($images_dir)) {
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($filename == "sprite.jpg") { $sprite_exists = true; break;}
        $fpath = $images_dir.'/'.$filename;
        if (exif_imagetype($fpath)      == IMAGETYPE_GIF)  { $list[] = $fpath; }
        else if (exif_imagetype($fpath) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) { $list[] = $fpath; }
        else if (exif_imagetype($fpath) == IMAGETYPE_PNG)  { $list[] = $fpath; }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
// Create a sprite image of all thumbnails
if ( ! $sprite_exists) {
    $sprite_height = $thumb_height * (count($list));
    // create the large sprite
    $sprite = imagecreatetruecolor($sprite_width, $sprite_height);
    // Set the background
    $black = imagecolorallocate($sprite, 0, 0, 0);
    imagefill($sprite, 0, 0, $black);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($list as $fpath){
        list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($fpath);
        if (exif_imagetype($fpath)      == IMAGETYPE_GIF)  { $source = imagecreatefromgif ($fpath); }
        else if (exif_imagetype($fpath) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) { $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($fpath); }
        else if (exif_imagetype($fpath) == IMAGETYPE_PNG)  { $source = imagecreatefrompng ($fpath); }
        $horizontal_position = 0;
        $vertical_position = $thumb_height * $i;
        $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;
        if ($ratio_orig > 1) {
            // Landscape
            $new_width  = $thumb_width;
            $new_height = intval($thumb_height / $ratio_orig);
            $vert_offset = intval(($thumb_height - $new_height)/2);
            $vertical_position += $vert_offset;
        } else if ($ratio_orig < 1) {
           // Portrait
            $new_width  = intval($thumb_width * $ratio_orig);
            $new_height = $thumb_height;
            $horiz_offset = intval(($thumb_width - $new_width)/2);
            $horizontal_position += $horiz_offset;
        } else {
           // Square
            $new_width  = $thumb_width;
            $new_height = $thumb_height;
        }
        imagecopyresampled($sprite, $source, $horizontal_position, $vertical_position, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
        $i++;
    }
    // Output and free from memory
    //imagejpeg($sprite, './images/sprite.jpg');
    imagejpeg($sprite, './sprite.jpg');
    imagedestroy($sprite);
}

// Generate the HTML to display thumbs from the sprite
$html = '<html><head><style type="text/css">.thumb{border:1px solid silver;height:'.$thumb_height.'px;width:'.$thumb_width.'px;
background-image:url(sprite.jpg);background-position: 0 -20px;display:inline-block;}</style></head><body>';
$i = 0;
foreach($list as $fpath){
    $vertical_offset = $thumb_height * $i;
    $thumb = '<a href="'.$fpath.'" class="thumb" style="background-position: 0 -'.$vertical_offset.'px">&nbsp;</a>';
    $html .= $thumb;
    $i++;
}
$html .= '</body></html>';
file_put_contents('thumbs.html',$html)
?>
```

Comment: when im trying this code it puts out nothing, a blank page.. i liked the idea but i want to see how it working. thanks!